# remove a content from xml Web Service

Tags: android

how can I remove a content from xml Web Service in android!!?
I wanna do the nxt: 1-after parsing the data from xml ws into listView. the user should choose one of the item which he wanna remove from the service! 
and the activity should reload and show the new list!
I wanna know how to `remove the Item from the ws` and how to `reload the page` !!

```
ListAdapter getCourseAdapter= new SimpleAdapter(this,coursesList,R.layout.taken_list,
                new String[] {"code","creditHours","name"}, new int[] 
                   {R.id.t3,R.id.hrs,R.id.desc});
        coursesLV.setAdapter(getCourseAdapter);

        coursesLV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,  final int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                     coursesList.remove(this);

                            }
                        });
```

Comment: You will need to send a request to the web service the actual call will depend on the web service you are using. Is it a public API, if it is post what it is and I/someone will have a look.

Comment: I send a req by using :HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
   HttpResponse httpResponse;
   HttpGet httpGet;???

Answer (score 0):

There should be one service for deleting the item. So when user click one the item first call a webservice to delete/remove the item from server.
Then call the webservice for reloading the listview again.

Comment: DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(URL);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();